# Trying to create a shape of an arrow with wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a shape like so:

----------> <----------

without the dashes and it has to be vertical...IS there an easy way to do this with 
the Line control in wpf in code behind?
Thnks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways of doing what you want.  Here is a simple way with the heights set.

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Line Grid.Row="0" Y1="0" Y2="35" X1="0" X2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Path Grid.Row="1" Data="M0,0 L5,10 L10,0Z" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Path Grid.Row="3" Data="M0,10 L5,0 L10,10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Line Grid.Row="4" Y1="0" Y2="35" X1="0" X2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

You can make the arrow heads closed, by adding a Z to the end of the Data property.  Setting a Fill value will color the arrow head.

Here is a great [link](http://charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/04/191200.html) for some cool Arrow stuff.